# Accessing Multiple web applications on Jboss7 or Wildfly

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8, wildfly-9, wildfly-10

I know we can deploy multiple web applications on JBoss 7 or Wildfly. But how can we access different web application with a different port? Where do we set that port for a web application?

For example,

- application1 is accessible on x.x.x.x:8080
- application2 is accessible on x.x.x.x:30000
- application3 is accessible on x.x.x.x:35000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your standalone you have to set up a different server and host for each application.

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">
    <server name="server1">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http-server1"/>
        <host name="webapp1" default-web-module="webapp1.war" alias="webapp1.com">
        </host>
    </server>
    <server name="server2">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http-server2"/>
        <host name="webapp2" default-web-module="webapp2.war" alias="webapp2.com">
        </host>
    </server>

    <!-- Other Settings -->
</subsystem>
```

For the socketbinding:

```xml
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="http-server1" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http-server2" port="${jboss.http.port:8081}"/>

    <!-- Other ports -->
</socket-binding-group>
```

And then finally, you can have your .war files in the deployments directory but for configurations like this I sometimes find it easier to set the runtime names explicitly:

```xml
<deployments>
    <deployment name="webapp1" runtime-name="webapp1.war">
            <fs-archive path="/path/to/webapp1.war" />
    </deployment>

    <deployment name="webapp2" runtime-name="webapp2.war">
            <fs-archive path="/path/to/webapp2.war" />
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```